# Append data on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have appended data in a kendo grid:

```
    $('.k-grid-Destroy span').append("<img src='/Content/img/icon_remove_16x16.png' alt='remove icon' />");
    $('.k-grid-editable span').append("<img src='/Content/img/edit_20px_enabled.png' alt='edit icon' />");
```

On grid refresh ( such as filtering ) the appended data gets erased and I'm not sure why. I tried to do some type of localStorage:

```
    var someVarName = $('.k-grid-Destroy span').append("<img src='/Content/img/icon_remove_16x16.png' alt='remove icon' />");
    $('.k-grid-editable span').append("<img src='/Content/img/edit_20px_enabled.png' alt='edit icon' />");
    localStorage.setItem("someVarName", someVarName);
```

but was unsuccessful. Is there a way to append the data and have it stay no matter on any refresh albeit page or grid refresh?

Comment: You aren't appending anything to the Kendo grid, you are appending a DOM element(img) to other DOM elements.  You need to make your buttons part of the grid definition, either using commands(http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.command) or using a column template with your buttons in it.(http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template)

Comment: ok ill take a look

Comment: yeah that worked man thanks